# Do we have to create Dialogfragment to allow Dialog to have title after API 21?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I found that after API21 my old dialog will lose the title. The minimal sample code is like this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button btn1;
    private Dialog testDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        testDialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClick);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showCopyDialog("some test");
            }
        });
    }

    private void showCopyDialog(final String address) {
        testDialog.setTitle(address);
        testDialog.setContentView(R.layout.copy_chip_dialog_layout);
        testDialog.setCancelable(true);
        testDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        Button button = (Button)testDialog.findViewById(android.R.id.button1);
        String buttonTitle = "Button Title";
        button.setText(buttonTitle);
        testDialog.show();
    }
}
```

And the layout for `copy_chip_dialog_layout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Copy Addresses"
    android:id="@android:id/button1"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_gravity="left"/>
```

In API21 it still can show the title while in API24 and API26, it cannot show title, I'm wondering if I have to create DialogFragment to add the title.

Answer (score 0):

Use **AlertDialog** you can show the dialog with a title in below and after 21.

Change your code like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button btn1;
    private AlertDialog testDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClick);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showCopyDialog("some test");
            }
        });
    }

    private void showCopyDialog(final String address) {
        AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        View dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.copy_chip_dialog_layout,null);
        dialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
        dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);
        Button button = (Button)dialogBuilder.findViewById(android.R.id.button1);
        button.setText("Button Title");
        testDialog= dialogBuilder.create();
        testDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Hope it helps:)

Comment: So basically you can't use Dialog directly?

Comment: Alertdialog from appcompat library will give you full support for old and new Api's